# Is there a convenient way to initialize simple structs in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, struct, initialization

Let's say I have a simple struct like this:

```
struct Simple
{
    int weight;
    std::string name;
    float power;
};
```

I'd like to be able to initialize one of these without creating a constructor for it and without having to individually set its parameters. I dream of a syntax like this, for example:

```
Simple s( 4, "bill", 3.1f );
```

...or perhaps...

```
Simple s = { 4, "bill", 3.1f };
```

...or verily...

```
Simple s{ 4, "bill", 3.1f };
```

I know that I can get the first example to work by adding a braindead constructor of my own. Tedious.

Likewise, the last example will work in C++11, but I believe I have to provide the constructor.

Is there a way to simply and elegantly initialize a struct in C++ without having to provide a constructor?

Comment: [Did you try those](http://ideone.com/JONZQp)?

Comment: Your second version should work with any version of C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simple s = { 4, "bill", 3.1f };

Simple s{ 4, "bill", 3.1f };
```

These are valid.

This syntax will map each value in the above groups/sets to each struct member variable depending on the order and you don't even need to define a constructor.

Comment: Hm. Wondering why it's not working for me then. Compiler support probably.

Comment: That was the case for me a couple of months ago. I updated my compiler and it all worked wonderfully.